# CSS: round corners + opacity = image disappears in Firefox 19

Tags: html, image, css, firefox

I want to add rounded corners to my images using CSS and also change the opacity on mouseover because this is cute. There's a bug: after mouseover, the image disappears.

The CSS is pretty simple:

```
.article img {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;  /* for Firefox */
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px; /* for Webkit-Browsers */
  border-radius: 15px; /* regular */
}

.article:hover .img {
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

html also just for a test (this is first image that I have googled):

```
<li class="article">
    <div class="img">
        <a href="#">
            <img src="http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/02371/karen-ann-jones_2371086k.jpg" alt="Url">
        </a>
    </div>
</li>
```

You can see it on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9DjLT/3/

**Browser: ff19**

Comment: works fine in chrome...what browser are you using?

Comment: question updated, ff19

Comment: What if on hover you change the opacity of the entire element, not just the image? `.article:hover { opacity: 0.8; }`

Comment: seems to work just fine in ff19 on my mac...

Comment: FF 19.0.2 on Win 8 and it works fine too. I just don't get what Mozilla is up to... FF seems to be getting worse with every version :D

Comment: Okay, let's take a step back. Ditch the rounded corners and see if opacity causes the image to disappear on hover. Let's try to isolate the problem.

Comment: works for me. both the corners and the opacity.

Comment: Yep. I can replicate this in FF 19.0.2 in Linux. Nasty one. Definitely a browser bug. Have simplified the example down to just an `<img>` inside a `<div>`, and it still happens.

Comment: NOW! With .article:hover (without img specifying) works for me in my project but not on jsfiddle! linux ff19

Comment: Wait a second, we're working with `img` AND `.img` — I just realized this...

Comment: @freemanoid: If it works outside of JSFiddle, then ignore JSFiddle. Not everything works correctly inside JSFiddle in all browsers.

Comment: Oh, I recently fell in css and already in sadness...
So is there are any complete solution for all browsers?

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/DRaaK/1/

Comment: @freemanoid Seems like it a FF on Linux issue. Maybe you should leave it or - if that's not an option - try to do what @couzzi wrote. Take step back and locate the problem. If you can't - try another approach (like change the css rule, i.e. `.article:hover img` or just `img:hover`. Good luck. :)

Comment: Thank you all for the help guys. Sorry that I can not up accept the comments, only a complete answer :). Could someone write a complete answer?

Comment: Your HTML is invalid! List items must be in a list...

Comment: Works fine for me in Firefox 19.0.2 on Windows.

Comment: I have same problem. img opacity:0.5 and border-radius:50%; It works well on Chrome and EI, but bugs in FF 19-21. I have win7 64bit.

Comment: This solved it: border:1px solid transparent;. I still wonder what's the cause. I could swear everything worked well yesterday.

Answer (score 4):

I encountered this problem recently while trying to implement block-level links on [my website](http://tracemeek.com/blog/), and I solved it by adding the following rule to the un-hovered img declaration:

```
border: 0.001em solid transparent;
```

A hack, to be sure, but it seems to work.

Comment: The construction in question (title of this page) works in all browsers that support both opacity and border-radius. In Firefox 20.0.1, the images were disappearing on "mouseout." Adding the thin transparent border fixed it for FF without affecting the rendering in other browsers.

Comment: You are right Trace Meek. This cured my css: border:1px solid transparent;

Comment: I was having a similar problem of a border-radius causing images to disappear using Ionic framework on Android (Chrome browser). This fix also worked for that.

Comment: As an addition this worked a bit better for me. The original code cut off some of the circle: `border: 1px hidden;`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have problem in css because of li:hover its taking 100% width. So till your mouse  cursor on li your image effect by opacity. Just try below change in CSS

```
.img a:hover{
  opacity: 0.8;
 }
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I hit a similar problem in Chrome 38.  In my case, I had a div with a `border-radius` value, and an image element with a transparency value, and the transparent image was hidden.  To fix this, I added a non-1 opacity to the parent element (with the border-radius).  Something like this:

```
.round_box {
  border-radius: 5px;
  opacity: 0.999999;
}

.transparent {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

<div class="round_box">
  <div class="transparent">
</div>
```

... Adding `opacity: 0.999999;` to the parent element made the transparent element display properly.  I should note that I also have a lot of other interesting styles going on - drop shadows, column layout - but, maybe a similar hack will work for others.